# tar: cowardly refusing to create an empty archive and I don't know why it would give me that error (files to be archived are not empty)

Tags: python, linux, sh, gzip, tar

I tried looking on stack overflow for a solution to this and other online resources but my specific situation didn't apply to what I found online.

When I run my script, it works until the line that I expect to create a tar archive of 2 files using the `os.system` command and store that archive in `/home/dahmed26/backups/xmlfiles`

It gives the following error:
`tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`
`Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.`
`sh: line 1: .tar.gz: command not found`

This is my code:

```
import os  
currentuser = os.popen('whoami')  
username = username.strip()  
if username != 'root':  
   print("Must be root")
   exit()
else:
   vmChoice = input("Choose a VM")
   now = os.popen('date +%Y%m%d').read()
   name = (vmChoice + '-' + now)
   os.system('virsh dumpxml ' + vmChoice + ' > /home/dahmed26/backups/xmlfiles/' + vmChoice + '.xml')
   location = os.popen('cat /home/dahmed26/backups/xmlfiles/' + vmChoice + '.xml | grep "source file" | cut -d "\'" -f2').read()
   os.system('tar czf' + ' ' + '/home/dahmed26/backups/xmlfiles/' + name + '.tar.gz' + ' ' + '/home/dahmed26/backups/xmlfiles/' + vmChoice + '.xml' + location)
```

Comment: It's Python. You can use `getpass.getuser()` to get the user, datetime to get the current time, and the `tarfile` module to make tar files.

Comment: If you are just using system tools, use a shell script.